# Naive Bayes Classifier in R (e1071) does not behave as expected (simple example)

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, classification, naivebayes

I don't understand why the following simple example:

```
genre <- c('ROMANCE', 'ROMANCE','ROMANCE', 'ACTION', 'ACTION', 'ACTION')
explosions <- c('NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES')
likeit <- c('DISLIKE', 'DISLIKE', 'DISLIKE', 'LIKE', 'LIKE', 'LIKE')

df <- data.frame(genre, explosions)
df[] <- lapply(df, factor)
df

model <- naiveBayes(df, as.factor(likeit))
model

p_genre <- factor('ACTION')
p_explosions <- factor('YES')
pred <- data.frame(genre=p_genre, explosions=p_explosions)
pred
model
predict(model, pred, type='raw')
```

With the following probabilities:

```
A-priori probabilities:
as.factor(likeit)
DISLIKE    LIKE 
    0.5     0.5 

Conditional probabilities:
                 genre
as.factor(likeit) ACTION ROMANCE
          DISLIKE      0       1
          LIKE         1       0

                 explosions
as.factor(likeit) NO YES
          DISLIKE  1   0
          LIKE     0   1

> predict(model, pred, type='raw')
     DISLIKE LIKE
[1,]     0.5  0.5
```

Doesn't give LIKE with prob 1 for an Action movie which has explosions.

Answer (score 3):

It is your factors that are incorrectly handled.

It works as expected if you do:

```
p_genre <- factor('ACTION', c('ACTION','ROMANCE'))
p_explosions <- factor('YES', c('NO', 'YES'))
pred <- data.frame(genre=p_genre, explosions=p_explosions)
predict(model, pred, type='raw')
```

you get:

```
         DISLIKE     LIKE
[1,] 9.99999e-07 0.999999
```